# How to use function written in C in Cython

Tags: python, c, numpy, cython

I have a function written in C, stored in two files; the header file and the c file. The cython docs only mention how to bring in the built in C functions into cython, such as stdio and stdlib. Here's what I'm trying to do:

```
from numpy import *


dir = loadtxt('cell_dirs_001.txt')
spk = loadtxt('cell_spks_001.txt')
pout = zeros(9)


cdef extern from "platemethod.h":
    double platemethod(double dir, double spk, 7, double pout)
```

Where dir and spks are both 5x8 arrays of doubles. I would post the platemethod files, but the function itself is about 200 lines long. Instead let's do this with a simpler example. Suppose I have a C function to test primality on a number, so two files that I create lets call them fib.c and fib.h. Here is fib.h:

```
void fib(int n)
```

Not much there, and probably not even necessary. However the big function has a header so we'll pretend it's a must. Here's fib.c:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include "fib.h"

void fib(int n){
    int n;
    int i = 2;    /* Obviously 1 can divide all and 2 is the base of primality*/
    while (i < n) {
        if (n % i == 0){
        return 0;
        break;
    }
        else {
        i = i + 1;
        if (i == (n-1)){
            return 1;
        }
    }

}

return 0;
}
```

Now to make it interesting, say I want to go through a list of numbers and see if they're prime.

```
a = [5,12,787,2,53334,12353112,12112478]
cdef extern from "fib.h":
    for n in a:
        print fib(n)
```

This doesn't work however. How could I go about this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You must basically repeat the header (.h) in the `.pyx` or `.pxd` file, with the appropriate changes whenever necessary.

With your simpler example, I had to change it a little bit. The `C` code had some issues (returning `int` inside the function but declaring it as `void`, also all the includes are unecessary for this case.)

```
int fib(int n){
    int i = 2;    /* Obviously 1 can divide all and 2 is the base of primality*/
    while (i < n) {
        if (n % i == 0){
            return 0;
            break;
        }
        else {
            i = i + 1;
            if (i == (n-1)){ return 1; }
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Your header should have a `;` after the definition:

```
void fib(int n);
```

The Cython file would be something like (I called `my_cython.pyx`):

```
cdef extern from './fib.h':
    int fib(int n)

cdef extern from './fib.c':
    pass

def function(n):
    return fib(n)
```

Then, after compiling, from a normal Python script:

```
from my_cython import function
print function(10)
```

This `cdef extern from *:` is a trick as explained in [Cython's "Tricks and Tips"](http://docs.cython.org/0.15/src/userguide/external_C_code.html). Sometimes you have to add:

```
cdef extern from *:
    pass
```

Comment: I did as you said, even added the cdef extern from * line. However when I make a setup.py file and go to compile it, it gives me this error: my_cython.pyx:9:14: Cannot convert 'void' to Python object

Comment: @NormanB I've edited the answer explaining all the issues I had to fix to make it run (now I tested here and it works!)

Comment: I'm still not getting it to work. What did you include in your setup.py file?

Comment: @NormanB [here is a gist of my setup](https://gist.github.com/saullocastro/7683277)

Comment: @NormanB [here is an useful link](https://github.com/saullocastro/cubature/tree/master/cubature) of a full Cython wrapper for a C package (cubature), check files `_cubature.pxd` and `_cubature.pyx`

Comment: Thanks a lot @Saullo, I appreciate it. I'm going to try this methodology with my big function, which I'll most likely have a bit of troubles with and post another more detailed question haha. Cheers